# Events generated when grabbing and moving the WinRT app window from the top edge with the mouse?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

On Windows 8, what kind of events are generated when moving the mouse cursor to the top edge and then click-dragging downwards with the left mouse button? It brings the window to a state where it can be docked to either side of the screen or exited by dragging it to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the Activated event in Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow. The callback function's args variable gives a WindowActivationState (Deactivated, CodeActivated or PointerActivated). An example of how to implement it can be found in the [Microsoft XAML DirectX 3d shooting game sample.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Metro-style-DirectX-18f98448)

Answer (score 0):

You do get the mouse move events, but there are no events fired to tell you that your app COULD change it's layout. You will be told when the app is snapped, filled, or landscape/portrait. If you are using the LayoutAwarePage, you will be told within the DetermineVisualState method.

```
    protected override string DetermineVisualState(ApplicationViewState viewState)
    {
        // Use the viewState property to determine layout
        return base.DetermineVisualState(viewState);
    }
```